# Create SQL SELECT Statement to 'modify' small table

Tags: sql, select

I am pretty new to SQL in general and want to 'modify' the following table (Tablename: translations / PK: id, language, key):

```
| id | language | key        | value        |
---------------------------------------------
| 1  | DE       | #Keyboard  | Tastatur     |   
| 1  | EN       | #Keyboard  | Keyboard     |   
| 1  | ES       | #Keyboard  | Teclado      |    
| 2  | DE       | #Screen    | Bildschirm   |  
| 2  | EN       | #Screen    | Screen       | 
| 3  | ES       | #Equipment | Equipo       |
```

I want to get a table like this:

```
| key        | valueDE      | valueEN      |
--------------------------------------------
| #Keyboard  | Tastatur     | Keyboard     | 
| #Screen    | Bildschirm   | Screen       |
| #Equipment | null         | null         |
```

So basically I want the translation of the values for the languages DE and EN next to each other in columns. Entries with no translation for DE and EN should have an empty field in the column valueDE and valueEN or if only one translation is available the other field in the column should be empty as shown in the table above.

Help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: I'd do a GROUP BY, and use case expressions to pick either EN or DE. You can also do a self (outer?) join.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, your definition re-worded into SQL.

```sql
select key,
  (select value from translations where language='DE' and key=t.key limit 1) "valueDE",
  (select value from translations where language='EN' and key=t.key limit 1) "valueEN"
from (select distinct key from translations) t;
```

| key | valueDE | valueEN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #Keyboard | Tastatur | Keyboard |
| #Equipment |  |  |
| #Screen | Bildschirm | Screen |

Comment: But if I a try it on a table with more entries I get an error: 'Single-row subquery returns more than one row'

Comment: I have patched the query. Please note however that you have more than one translation for the same pair (key, language) in table `translations`

Comment: I found a solution for bigger tables by using the MAX() aggregate function around 'value'

Comment: Better address the core problem. It is not that the table is bigger but the same (key, language) has more than one translation somewhere in `translations` and this seems to me very wrong. Using `MAX` patches the issue but is semantically very questionable. So is `limit 1` btw.

Comment: Good point. I will try to solve the core problem then.